# How to make tab content active in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I make the `London` tab contents active when opening the page?

I have tried to set the classes to "active" but it didn't help.

This is the script:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
     overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

 /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
 .tab button {
background-color: inherit;
float: left;
border: none;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 14px 16px;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;
}

  /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
 .tab button.active {
background-color: #ccc;
 }

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
display: none;
padding: 6px 12px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>London</h3>
 <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>Paris</h3>
 <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>Tokyo</h3>
 <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";

}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I got the script from: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just manually add `display: block` to the `London` tab by default and let JS toggle the display properties itself after that like this:

```
<div id="London" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;">
```

Or if you want to use JS too for adding the inital `display: block` to the London tab, you can add these two lines above your `openCity` function:

```
var londonTab = document.getElementById("London");
londonTab.style.display = "block";
```

---

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/202bou56/

Comment: Glad I could help mate. Do mark this as the correct answer if it helped you solve your issue. Also, I added a js approach to adding the `display: block` to your london tab just in case you need a pure js approach to fixing this. But the html approach works fine too.

Comment: I am using the html approach in this matter. either way both of them perfectly works like a charm. again, thanks for your reply @AndrewL !

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JS solution**: Change line

```
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
```

to

```
document.getElementById(cityName).className += " active";
```

And At the bottom of your script (line above `</script>` closing tag) put

```
openCity(null, 'London');
```

that's all. However you don't need to use JS at all - look to @AndrewL [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50297992/860099).

Comment: If you do that then you will get an error because the that code is working with event.target and you are setting it to `null`

Comment: yes and apparently when you changed tab, you cant get back to London.

Comment: thank you for the reply and update @KamilKiełczewski I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can upvote my answer by click on gray "up" triangle on the left